# Fire event once when numerical condition is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I'm running this little piece of Javascript:

```
if(path.length >= 7000){

    alert("OVER 7000");
}
```

In this script, `path.length` is a variable which begins at 0 and increments to 7000 (and beyond) - further details aren't relevant.

What I want is that the alert message appears *only once* when the 7000 value is met and then fires no more. (At the moment, I get an incessant stream of alerts once 7000 is met.)

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple flag to determine if you've alerted:

```
var alerted = false;
// ...
if(path.length >= 7000 && !alerted) {
    alert("OVER 7000");
    alerted = true;
}
```

Or if you post how you're looping and incrementing `path.length`, you can probably do something with a `while` loop and a `break`.

Comment: That certainly looks good, but it doesn't seem to work... I still get incessant alerts. And apropos your second recommendation, it's not a looping function that's incrementing `path.length`

Comment: Move `var alerted = false;` outside of the `onMouseMove` event, so it's global. Right now, you set it to false every time the mouse moves

Comment: I just saw that! Thanks for solving that bit too! And a useful trick that flagging one.